# Use of CONCAT FLOOR Statement

Tags: mysql

I need to create a frequency table that displays the revenue per bin. The bin has a range of 500. The code shown below almost do the work except it is displaying a different values:

```
SELECT IF(rng='1 - 500','0 - 500',rng)AS Revenue,
       IFNULL(B.rngcount,0)AS Count 
FROM
    (
    SELECT '1 - 500' rng UNION
    SELECT '501 - 1000'   UNION
    SELECT '1001 - 1500'  UNION
    SELECT '1501 - 2000'  UNION
    SELECT '2001 - 2500'
   ) A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR((product.price * line_item.quantity)/500)*500+1,' - ',FLOOR((product.price * line_item.quantity)/500)*500+500) rng, 
                  COUNT(1) rngcount 
           FROM  line_item, product 
           GROUP BY rng) B USING (rng);
```

Comment: Do you really need CROSS JOIN over `line_item` and `product` tables? looks like WHERE clause is lost...

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables, some example data as INSERT INTO and desired output for this data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I use join because the data is coming from two tables. product and line_item. Can you help me how to make it work?

Comment: *I use join because the data is coming from two tables. product and line_item* You use not JOIN (each row from A to each related row from B) but CROSS JOIN (each row from A to each row from B, even when they are not related to each other). *how to make it work?* provide everything mentioned above.

Comment: Okay let me try to edit my post

Comment: I have already attach the database so that you can review it. Thank you Akina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(ranges.lo, ' - ', ranges.hi) Revenue,
       COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    1 lo,  500 hi UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000    UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500    UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000    UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lo AND ranges.hi
GROUP BY ranges.lo, ranges.hi;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9231b2684397cdce045ac396c68bc081)

---

As I have commented - the relation between `product` and `line_item` must be specified. Common column for them is `product_id` - so according joining condition added.

And ranges table is used in a form from-to, this simplifies checking what range the revenie is posessed in.

---

> is it possible to sum the Count column, and place the total.

Easily.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(ranges.lo, ' - ', ranges.hi) Revenue,
       COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    1 lo, 500 hi UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000   UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500   UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000   UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lo AND ranges.hi
GROUP BY Revenue WITH ROLLUP;
```

Totals row is the last, with NULL value in `Revenue` column.

Comment: This is an amazing code you did. You saved my day. You are great Akina.

Comment: Follow up question Sir Akina, is it possible to sum the Count column, and place the total. Kindly show the solution.

Comment: Great. Is it also possible to cross tabulate the result. Say I want to display the products (soda,liquor,lemon,mango,inhaler) in columns, in between Revenue and Count. And the data would fall in its respective range with their total below?

Comment: @KRISTOFFERMORADA This is called a PIVOT. MySQL does not support it. Of course you may emulate it (by conditional aggregation for static products list or by stored procedure with dynamic SQL for dynamic products list), but I'd recommend to perform this action on the client side using its reporting service which must support pivot tables.

Comment: I mean the same.

Comment: I have added a third image of what I have in mind about cross-tabulation. Hope you can make it work. Thank you.

Comment: And again - I mean the same.

Comment: (Of course you may emulate it (by conditional aggregation for static products list or by stored procedure with dynamic SQL for dynamic products list)...How can this work sir?

Comment: This is a question which is (1) separate (2) not easy in realization. Search the site using searching string `PIVOT [mysql]` and read the questions and solutions - this must give you the way.

Comment: Thank you sir Akina. You have been such a great help.

Comment: I have been able to cross tabulate the data with the result I wish to see. Just one problem, is there such a way to replace the NULL with a word when the ROLLUP is used?

Comment: Use the query as subquery. Replace NULL with the value which you need in outer query: `SELECT COALESCE(category, 'TOTALS') category, .. FROM (SELECT .. GROUP BY category WITH ROLLUP) AS subquery`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I made to group the revenue according to week.Maybe you can still simplify this.

```
    (sales_agent.name)AS Agent, 
    (sales_team.name)AS Team, 
    
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=1), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS Week_1, 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=2), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS Week_2, 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=3), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS Week_3,
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=4), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS Week_4,
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=5), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS Week_5,
    SUM(product.price * line_item.quantity) AS Total
FROM ((((line_item
INNER JOIN order_ ON line_item.order_id = order_.order_id)
INNER JOIN sales_agent ON order_.agent_id = sales_agent.agent_id)
INNER JOIN sales_team ON sales_agent.team_id  = sales_team.team_id)
INNER JOIN product ON line_item.product_id = product.product_id)
GROUP BY sales_agent.agent_id;
```